# Remove the first character of each line and append using Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have a data file as follows.

```
1,14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92,1065
1,13.2,1.78,2.14,11.2,100,2.65,2.76,.26,1.28,4.38,1.05,3.4,1050
1,13.16,2.36,2.67,18.6,101,2.8,3.24,.3,2.81,5.68,1.03,3.17,1185
1,14.37,1.95,2.5,16.8,113,3.85,3.49,.24,2.18,7.8,.86,3.45,1480
1,13.24,2.59,2.87,21,118,2.8,2.69,.39,1.82,4.32,1.04,2.93,735
```

Using vim, I want to reomve the 1's from each of the lines and append them to the end. The resultant file would look like this:

```
14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92,1065,1
13.2,1.78,2.14,11.2,100,2.65,2.76,.26,1.28,4.38,1.05,3.4,1050,1
13.16,2.36,2.67,18.6,101,2.8,3.24,.3,2.81,5.68,1.03,3.17,1185,1
14.37,1.95,2.5,16.8,113,3.85,3.49,.24,2.18,7.8,.86,3.45,1480,1
13.24,2.59,2.87,21,118,2.8,2.69,.39,1.82,4.32,1.04,2.93,735,1
```

I was looking for an elegant way to do this.

Actually I tried it like

```
:%s/$/,/g
```

And then

```
:%s/$/^./g
```

But I could not make it to work.

**EDIT :** Well, actually I made one mistake in my question. In the data-file, the first character is not always 1, they are mixture of 1, 2 and 3. So, from all the answers from this questions, I came up with the solution --

```
:%s/^\([1-3]\),\(.*\)/\2,\1/g
```

and it is working now.

Comment: The substitution s/$/,/g says to replace the end of the line marker, which is 0 width, with a comma.  The substitution s/&/^./ doesn't really make sense: you are asking to replace the end-of-line-marker with the beginning-of-the-line-marker followed by a dot.  The beginning-of-the-line-marker will never be at the end of a line, so vim decides you must mean a literal '^'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular expression that doesn't care which number, its digits, or separator you've used. That is, this would work for lines that have both `1` as their first number, or `114`:

```
:%s/\([0-9]*\)\(.\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/
```

**Explanation:**

```
:%s//           - Substitute every line (%)
\(<something>\) - Extract and store to \n
[0-9]*          - A number 0 or more times
.               - Every char, in this case,
.*              - Every char 0 or more times
\3\2\1          - Replace what is captured with \(\)
```

**So:** Cut up `1` `,` `<the rest>` to `\1`, `\2` and `\3` respectively, and reorder them.

Comment: @ramgorur np. My regex might not be the easiest, but it's the most flexible if you want to move multiple numbers of different digits.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
:%s/^1,//
:%s/$/,1/
```

could be somewhat simpler to understand.

Comment: this should be the right answer because this answers the question exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/^1,\(.*\)/\1,1/
```

This will do the replacement on each line in the file.  The `\1` replaces everything captured by the `(.*)`

Comment: Pretty sure you need to escape capturing parens in vim.

Comment: If you use the "very magic" (see `:help \magic`) option you don't have to escape capturing parens (or a bunch of other special characters like {}, |, etc). Try with the search prefixed with `\v`: `:%s/\v^1(.*)/\1,1/`. Note: in very magic mode, if you want to match a paren (or the other special character) you must escape it.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/1,\(.*$\)/\1,1/gc
```

.........................

Answer (score 1):

You could also solve this one using a macro. First, think about how to delete the `1,` from the start of a line and append it to the end:

```
0 go the the start of the line
df, delete everything to and including the first ,
A,<ESC> append a comma to the end of the line
p paste the thing you deleted with df,
x delete the trailing comma
```

So, to sum it up, the following will convert a single line:

```
0df,A,<ESC>px
```

Now if you'd like to apply this set of modifications to all the lines, you will first need to record them:

```
qj start recording into the 'j' register
0df,A,<ESC>px convert a single line
j go to the next line
q stop recording
```

Finally, you can execute the macro anytime you want using `@j`, or convert your entire file with `99@j` (using a higher number than 99 if you have more than 99 lines).

Here's the complete version:

```
qj0df,A,<ESC>pxjq99@j
```

This one might be easier to understand than the other solutions if you're not used to regular expressions!

Comment: it would be more helpful if you could explain the command. I have never seen such notations before in VIM.

Comment: Okay, I have split the command up in the different sub-commands it consists of. I hope you will find it useful!